# DataInputStream's readFully query

Tags: java, sockets, datainputstream

I am using dataInputStream's readFully message to read a fixed length byte array as:

```
byte[] record = new byte[4660004];

in.readFully(record);
```

The problem here is that sometimes it takes more than 5 seconds to read these many bytes, which is equal to 20000 records. And I am receiving this data on socket. Client is sending data as byte array of 4660004 bytes. Is there a way to received this data faster as right now it takes about 5 minutes to 1 million such records.

EDIT:: complete data flow :

first I create the stream :

```
static DataInputStream dIn = null;

dIn = new DataInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
msgType = dIn.readByte();

int msgIntLen = dIn.readInt();

processBatch(msgIntType, msgIntLen, dIn, connector);

.
.

private static void processBatch(int msgIntType, int msgIntLen, DataInputStream in,
            Connector connector) throws IOException {

   int recordIntLen = in.readInt();
   byte[] record = new byte[msgIntLen - 4];
   in.readFully(record);

}
```

where should I include the Buffering if that wudf help ?

Comment: Is your DataInputStream wrapping a BufferedInputStream?

Comment: @Nathan - no. how can i do this ? please see my code in EDIT to see how really I am processing.

Comment: Try this: `dln = new DataInputStream(new java.io.BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream()));`

Comment: Doing so may not solve your performance issue. It depends on the nature of the input stream being returned by the socket implementation, but it couldn't hurt.

Comment: @Nathan - what can I do at client to solve this performance issue ? I mean, how can I buffer client's DataOutputStream ?

Comment: You can do the same thing, but with a `BufferedOutputStream`: `dOut = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(...));`

Answer (score 0):

Comments are beginning to scroll, so moving to an answer.

Buffer your output on the client side by using a BufferedOutputStream. Make sure to call `dlOut.flush()` after writing the data, so that unsent bytes don't remain in the buffered output stream.

Buffer your input on the client side by using a BufferedInputStream.

Because you are just sending byte arrays, you probably don't need the DataInputStream/DataOuputStream, unless you are using them for an additional purpose. You could just be using BufferedInputStream/BufferedOutputStream.